# Are play-json writes suppose to support indexed path?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I'm trying to write a wrapper over play-json and kind of bump into this. I want to serialize a simple value, say a string, to a specific path, like this :

`(JsPath \ "string" \ 0 \ "test").write[String].writes("test")`

In response I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: expected KeyPathNode` which point to `JsPath.scala: 149`

At this line, a match clause clearly throw if an index is in the path, but why ?
To me it seems clear I want an array in my json.

Comment: You might be thinking about this wrong. You should parse the whole json, not just the bits you want..

Comment: Sorry but I am writing JSON  not parsing.